# How to get distinct column from the table and compare this column with other table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, TABLE A AND TABLE B.

**TABLE A:**

| patient id | Session id |
| --- | --- |
| Pat1 | Sess1_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess1_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess1_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess2_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess2_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess2_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess4_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess4_P1 |
| Pat2 | Sess1_P2 |
| Pat2 | Sess1_P2 |
| Pat2 | Sess2_P2 |
| Pat2 | Sess2_P2 |

**TABLE B**

| patient id | Session id |
| --- | --- |
| Pat1 | Sess1_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess2_P1 |
| Pat1 | Sess3_P1 |
| Pat2 | Sess1_P2 |
| Pat2 | Sess2_P2 |

I want to get the resultant table to be like this by using mysql query.

| Session id Table A | Session id Table B |
| --- | --- |
| Sess1_P1 | Sess1_P1 |
| Sess2_P1 | Sess2_P1 |
| Sess3_P1 |  |
|  | Sess4_P1 |
| Sess1_P2 | Sess1_P2 |
| Sess2_P2 | Sess2_P2 |

Comment: wait a while for me to do it and I will explain it and so on.

Comment: one question the table of what it returns is exactly that or similar?

Comment: Let me know if mine works for you and is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tableA.session_id, tableB.session_id
FROM ( SELECT patient_id, session_id
       FROM tableA
       UNION 
       SELECT patient_id, session_id
       FROM tableB ) base
NATURAL LEFT JOIN tableA
NATURAL LEFT JOIN tableB
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f026d8bdd6357f77af5cfee2cb062ba

Comment: It gives me error whenever I add distinct in the query. Can u plz tell where to put the distinct?. Only Table A entries are not unique.

Comment: Thankyou for the information Akina, But I am still not getting the desired results. It still has repeated entries.

Comment: Still not working, TableB.session_id column is empty while tableA.session_id column has the session_id values after executing this query.

Comment: @MakM Fiddle shows that the output of my query matches your desired output completely. If you cannot obtain the same output then you do something wrongly.

Comment: to be honest I have tried @Akina's solution and it returns exactly what you wanted, so you should check the checkbox or modify your question to what you want, I already voted positive for it

Comment: @Akina so what I have figured out in my database that the session ids are not sorted that's why the second column is not showing any value. I am modifying the question, where my tables will not be sorted, what should be the query to sort both the ids and then compare?
**modified table B**

Comment: @Akina 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=486f75856f8634cba80b0f0e55141f8d
does not give the desired input after modifying, the main issue is to get the sorted session ids.

Comment: @MakM Providing the fiddle you must always check that it does not contain any misprinting, and that all queries are executed without errors. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9958ff93a373cdc611c95d3e89dc62e9 Providing the fiddle where the output does not match desired one you must provide this desired output at least (the best way - with detailed explanations what is the kind of the incorrectness).

Comment: Thankyou for the information. @Akina
Can you please tell if there is any way we can modify the query to get this output, by using the modified table B. If not, I will edit the question and will accept your answer because it helped in the previous case.